# Override CSS class from ASP.NET MVC back-end

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having CSS class which looks like this:

```
.myClass {
    background-color: #A5A5A5;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I have table in database which has record for customization of the background color for myClass. I need to get the new value (ex. #000000) from the database and **override the value in myClass** (#A5A5A5).

Is there anyway I can do this in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: You would either need to create a dynamic stylesheet that ued your db values or you culd add it to your model and insert it inline on the element